# Why my function incrementing plus 2?

Tags: javascript, increment

Hello I wrote a function :

```
$(function() {
    $('button').on('click', function() {
        var $tile = $('.tile');
        for (i = 1; i <= 16; i++)
        $("#board").append('<div id="c' + ($tile.length + i++) + '" class="card"></div>');
    });
});
```

Why it is incrementing my id's by 2 instead of 1?

Thanks for answers anyone. That was really stupid mistake...

Comment: ($tile.length + i++) should be ($tile.length + i)

Comment: i++ and i++ again...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are incrementing i at two places.

Inside for loop

```
for (i = 1; i <= 16; i++)
```

and

```
$tile.length + i++
```

Because of this it is incrementing two times

Answer (score 4):

The code `i++` increments `i`.  You have this code twice in your loop: once in the loop statement itself, and once inside loop in the DOM code.  You need to remove or the other.  It's natural to increment `i` in the loop, so remove the other by changing this:

```
$tile.length + i++
```

to just:

```
$tile.length + i
```

Answer (score 4):

you are incrementing `i` twice.

```js
$(function() {
    $('button').on('click', function() {
        var $tile = $('.tile');
        for (i = 1; i <= 16; i++)
        $("#board").append('<div id="c' + ($tile.length + i) + '" class="card"></div>');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You are incrementing by 1 twice:

1. The first in your loop statement

   ```
   for (i = 1; i <= 16; i++)
   ```
2. And then again in the loop body

   ```
   ($tile.length + i++)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Don't increment i again in this:
($tile.length + i++)

instead do this:
($tile.length + i)